# Changing desktop background and playing .mp3 file is not working

Tags: python, audio, visual-studio-code, mp3, desktop-background

```py
import ctypes
import winsound
SPI_SETDESKWALLPAPER = 20 
while (True):
    x = input("Enter Password. ")
        if x == "blyat":
        print ("motherland russia")
        ctypes.windll.user32.SystemParametersInfoW(SPI_SETDESKWALLPAPER, 0, "D:\\VS Code Project\\COMMUNISM.jpg", 0)
        winsound.PlaySound("USSR Anthem.mp3", winsound.SND_FILENAME)
```

When I run the program, I can't hear the .mp3 and the desktop background goes black instead of changing to the image I selected (COMMUNISM.jpg)

Comment: Won't the loop set the background and play the sound over and over again? Have you tried it without the loop?

Answer (score 0):

Based on the information you provided, I did the following:

1. Install the module "`playsound`" and add it to use: (`pip install playsound`)

> `from playsound import playsound`

2. Use "`playsound('D:\\...\\Ze\\1.mp3')`" instead of "`winsound.PlaySound("D:\\...\\Ze\\1.mp3", winsound.SND_FILENAME)`"

**Complete code:**

```
from playsound import playsound  
import ctypes
import winsound
SPI_SETDESKWALLPAPER = 20 
while (True):
    x = input("Enter Password:")
    if x == "blyat":
        print ("motherland russia")
        
        ctypes.windll.user32.SystemParametersInfoW(SPI_SETDESKWALLPAPER, 0, "D:\\...\\Ze\\1.jpg", 0)
      # winsound.PlaySound("D:\\...\\Ze\\1.mp3", winsound.SND_FILENAME)
        playsound('D:\\...\\Ze\\1.mp3')
```

The result of my test on my computer is that the desktop wallpaper was changed and the mp3 played.